# Is my express post request is correct?

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I'm trying to understand how Post Request works with express. I my case I would like to be able to update an web API call (is this the right term ?) with Google Analytics API. Most of the examples I found here or there are about handling post message or sign in operation.

Following this [question](http://www.vardump.pw/sc?id=is38988886) here is what I have understand. On the front-end, using axios here is what I need to pass :

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/endpoints", my_parameters)
```

I can easily send this on the server side with react/redux. however on the server side, I'm kind of lost. I've got the following API call :

```
var key = require('./client_id.json')
var jwtClient = ...

var VIEW_ID = "ga:80820965";

var authorize = function( cb ) {
  jwtClient.authorize(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    } else {
      if ( typeof cb === "function") {
        cb();
      }
    }
  });
}

var queryData = function(req, res) {
  authorize(function() {
    analytics.data.ga.get({
      'auth': jwtClient,
      'ids': VIEW_ID,
      'metrics': 'ga:uniquePageviews',
      'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
      'sort': '-ga:uniquePageviews',
      'max-results': 10,
    }, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      res.send(response);
    }); 
  });
}

module.exports = {
    queryData
};
```

and my express server set-up :

```
const app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('public'));
app.use('/', express.static('src'));

var ga = require('./src/apicall/gadata');

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.set('views', './src/views');      
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/gadata', ga.queryData);
```

so after I've dispatched my `axios.post`, how do I handle it in my `server.babel.js` file ?

I guess I need to use a structure like this :

```
router.get('/newUser', (req, res) => {
  TestUser.save({
    name: 'sawyer',
    email: 'sawyer@test.com'
  }).then((result) => {
    console.log('Saved!')
    res.send(result)
  })
})
```

but I don't really know how I should refactor it to pass my parameters so I can actually update my google analytics api call ?

thanks.

Comment: You have a function defined inside your `app.post()` handler that isn't getting called.  That does not make sense and your code looks to me like it would generate a parse error (not even correct Javascript code).

Comment: The point is I don't really understand how I should link my web API call and my `app.post` function. From the examples I've read `app.post` deliver data from an endpoint. however It doesn't help me to build a dynamic API call... I don't know if you understand my issue.

Comment: You aren't showing valid Javascript and you aren't describing in detail exactly what you're trying to achieve.  Not much we can do to help you when your question is this vague and unclear.  It is your responsibility to make your question clear enough that folks here can understand it and can then help you.  Usually, the point of a POST is to submit some data, but you don't even show an attempt to use any data that was submitted with the POST.  Thoroughly confused about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback. The thing is I don't really now where I should start. I don't find the word to explain what I'm trying to do. To put it simply I want to be able to update a google analytics API call on my server-side with some value coming from my front-end. From what I have understand I need to do an AJAX request/Post request. However I don't understand how this should help me to update my google analytics api parameters (metrics, dimensions,etc...) I can't find any example and I don't know where to start to explain my issue or revole it.

Comment: Well, the only way you can get an answer here is to find clear enough words to describe what you're trying to accomplish and put that IN your question.  We can't read your mind, so you have to describe it in words/code.  You can use the "edit" link to modify your existing question.  Imagine you were hiring someone to write this code for you.   How would you explain to them what you want to do?

Comment: Ok. I've updated my post. hope it's clearer.